# Density of polynomials with a prescribed number field extension

Tags: nt.number-theory

For any polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, let $K_f$ denote the minimum splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ which contains all of the roots of $f$. Let $n \geq 2$ be a fixed integer, and let $K$ be a fixed number field which is the splitting field of some polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $n$. Let

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{S}_N = \{f(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]: |a_i| \leq N, i = 0, \cdots, n, K_f = K \}.$$

Then is there an estimate for the quantity

$$\displaystyle \# \mathcal{S}_N/N^{n+1}?$$

More precisely, can we obtain an exact asymptotic formula, in terms of $N$ and $K$, for $\# \mathcal{S}_N$?

Comment: It presumably goes to $0$. Consider the case $n = 2$ for concreteness.

Comment: I modified the question to be more precise and non-trivial.

Comment: As the coefficients $a_i$ can lie between $-N$ and $N$, should not the  definition of density have $(2N)^{n+1}$ in the denominator?

Comment: or rather $(2N+1)^{n+1}$? (I missed zero!)

Answer (score -1):

This sort of question goes back to van der Waerden (who showed that "most" polynomials have the full symmetric group as the Galois group). The most recent (and most relevant) result of this sort are due to Dietmann, and in
Dietmann, Rainer(4-LNDHB)
On the distribution of Galois groups. (English summary) 
Mathematika 58 (2012), no. 1, 35–44.

he showed that the number of monic polynomials of height $H$ (your $N$) with fixed Galois group $G$ is bounded as $$\ll_{n, \epsilon} H^{n-1 +\frac{|G|}{n!} + \epsilon}.$$
Your question is not quite the same, but close enough.

Comment: I think this is quite different from the question asked...